# Does Tony Stark have a self-flying helicopter?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, iron-man, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*,

> Tony Stark takes a helicopter to visit his friends at a secret containment facility.

He then decides to go after

> Captain America, and so activates his Iron Man suit and drops out of his helicopter.

He apparently

> leaves his helicopter hanging in midair.

This leaves no one flying the helicopter. Does this mean that it can fly itself?

**Does Tony Stark have a self-flying helicopter?**

Comment: Haven't seen the film yet, so I'm not going to mouse-over, but my first thought is, why not? Just leave it in the capable hands of Jarvis.

Comment: Cruise control!

Comment: @MrLister don't you mean FRIDAY, not JARVIS?

Comment: @RedCaio Like I said, I haven't seen the film yet.

Comment: You mean like a quad copter? I'm sure he does. They're like $19.99 from China. jk jk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the evidence suggests that he does. If there's nobody else on board to pilot the helicopter - and, from memory, it didn't appear that there was -  then there are only two options: it can fly itself to a set destination or it's going to crash. The second option would be counter-productive when you want people to think you're on board that same helicopter.

Considering the level of technology we've seen in the MCU in general, and especially the technology we've seen from Tony Stark (in particular Iron Man suits that are capable of functioning autonomously or of being controlled by JARVIS), a self flying helicopter isn't that surprising. It is, to be honest, one of the next logical steps after driverless cars (which the MCU [totally has](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/57244/5833)).

Comment: There is one segment where the camera pans from Tony to the front window. It is very clear there is no pilot (or anybody else) aboard.

Comment: I still prefer his self-driving R8.